# jquery ajax Send string data and file data PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a file to the php file through ajax, the problem is when I try to send the data I need to sent it as String (mandatory) to locate the controller and the action (function) in this way:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/app/controllers/router.php",
            data: {
               controller: 'resource_management/language_control', action: "createLanguageControl", user: User, language: Language, course: Course, begin_date: BeginDate, end_date: EndDate, installments: Installments, monthly_amount: MonthlyAmount, max_reimbursement: MaxReimbursement, currency: Currency, TempDir : tempDir, DocName : docName
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (r) {
            ...
});
```

So it passes by the router and read the controller and the action by string.
How do I sent the file?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question earlier? I gave you a link to another question that shows how to do it.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/12352/php-simple-crud-ajaxmysqli.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
var file = "someFile.csv";
var data = new FormData();

var controllerData = JSON.stringify({
    controller: "resource_management/language_control",
    action: "createLanguageControl",
    .....
});
data.append("file", file);
data.append("string", controllerData);

$.ajax({
    url: '/app/controllers/router.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```